# Typo3 local installation on webserver

Tags: php, xampp, webserver, typo3, fluid

My local installation of a `Typo3` Page worked perfectly fine on a `Xampp Server` but when I tried moving it to my webserver I get the error

The Fluid template files [Path to my layout.html] could not be loaded.
More information regarding this error might be available online.

I transferred the files from Htdocs with FTP and the database with `phpmyadmin` import/export.

What could cause this error?

Comment: Check Uppercase syntax for FLUID template filenames. I guess you are using TYPO3 CMS 8. FLUID template filenames should start with an uppercase letter. This can be handled different on different OS systems.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I probably would have never find that out. You saved me from a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In this generality there are multiple reasons possible:

Can the apache user access the files? (the FTP user mostly is different than the apache user and the correct file- und folder-permissions can be lost easily)

Have you the same filenames and pathes?
don't use the windows folder separator `\` on unix-servers.
is your local file systems case insensitive? Linux is case sensitive and `/test/`is another folder than `/Test/`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your correct domain record on the pagge tree root?

If not please set the domain record to the actual url you try to reach the page.